# Spring Kafka auto commit offset, commits same offset at commit interval even if there are no records to read?

Tags: apache-kafka

Spring Kafka with the following configuration,

```
enable.auto.commit = true
auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000
```

The topic receives no messages for few days, So my Kafka consumer will commit the same offset again and again at the interval provided?

Will it help in keeping the offset write to broker active, so that the  `offsets.retention.minutes = 1440` (Kafka 0.10.2 default) property doesn't kick in and resets the offset.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're actually trying to ask, but this seems easy to test

Comment: You should really upgrade your broker. 0.10.x.x is ancient. Since 2.1, offsets are retained for 7 days (by default) since the last consumer was active. 2.0 changed the default to 7 days, but the retention could still elapse even when consumers were active.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks, tested it out, auto.commit = true, keeps on committing the offset in an async manner in the background even if there are no messages to process, and hence helps in keeping the offset alive. 

Yes, We should get our Kafka updated to 2.x. For now, I have updated the offsets.retention.minutes=10080 (7 days) in Kafka broker.

Comment: It keeps the group alive, but the retention policies are still in effect for the consumed topic, so after a week, old segments will still be rolled and the offset will be reset to whatever is available (even if earliest and newest offset are equal)